# The Lucas argument vs the theorem-provers -- who wins and why?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, mathematical-philosophy, proof-assistants

In his paper, "Minds, Machines and Gödel", J.R. Lucas writes the following:

> Gödel's theorem [First Incompleteness Theorem, that is—my comment] must apply to cybernetic machines, because it is of the essence of being a machine, that it should be a concrete instantiation of a formal system.  It follows that given any machine which is consistent and capable of doing simple arithmetic, there is a formula which it is incapable of producing as being true—i.e., the formula is unprovable-in-the-system—but which we can see to be true.  It follows that no machine can be a complete or adequate model of the mind, that minds are essentially different from machines.

Contrariwise, the following papers,

> Wilfrid Sieg and Clinton Field, "[Automated search for Gödel's Proofs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007204001393)", *Annals of Pure and Applied Logic* 133 (2005) 319-338 ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2126564))
>
> Lawrence C. Paulson, "[A Mechanized Proof of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems using Nominal Isabelle](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Formath/Goedel-ar.pdf)" ([published](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10817-015-9322-8)

suggest that computers can not only show that the Gödel sentence is not provable from ZF − *Infinity*, but can also show that it is true, provided ZF − *Infinity* is consistent.

Why this is important is because Lucas, in the paragraph I quoted, makes the mistake that we as humans 'see' that the Gödel sentence is true.  In point of fact, we actually *infer* the truth of the Gödel sentence much as a theorem-prover might infer its truth (if in fact the theorem-prover (via its respective metatheory) can infer the truth of the Gödel sentence, assuming ZF − *Infinity* is consistent).

So that is the question before us:  Can computers that run theorem-proving software infer that that the Gödel sentence is true (note that Sieg and Field, as well as Paulson, use ZF − *Infinity* rather than PA as the object-theory for their theorem-proving software).

Comment: The argument by Lucas you quote reminds me of Penrose's book "shadows of the mind".

Comment: Since PA+CON(PA)$\vdash$G (the Gödel sentence), humans start by assuming PA is true and therefore consistent, so they infer that G is true.  That is, humans use CON(PA) in their inference, rather than PA alone.  It's unsurprising that adding this independent postulate lets them prove things that PA can't prove by itself.

Comment: PA itself can prove Gödel's incompleteness theorem for PA, which itself is an implication that Con(PA) implies that its Gödel in unprovable. What it can't do (if it is consistent) is prove the the hypothesis of that conditional. The fact that automatic theorem provers can prove Gödel's theorem doesn't by itself say that such theorem provers go beyond what can be proved in PA. I'm not a great fan of Lucas's argument, but I don't think that these papers by themselves are particularly relevant.

Comment: This (from Lucas) is nonsense and based on a misunderstanding of Goedel's theorems. What does it mean to say that a person can 'see a statement is true'? If it should mean anything, it means we have some way to demonstrate it is true. But a computer can generate any proof a human can generate; and if the proof is correct then a computer can check it as well as a human. (Both of these are true in principle, in practice it remains the case that a human can generate interesting proofs vastly faster than a computer and can also check much more easily).

Comment: Lucas' argument seems to assume there are no true statement the human mind can't prove, which seems highly unlikely. It may already been proved dead wrong, as I remember seeing that it was proven that is impossible to prove some statements to be either correct or wrong. The mind itself seems no better than any formal system.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN:  If you take a look at Penrose's earlier book, _The Emporer's New Mind_, I think you will find that book reference's Lucas' Argument explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I read Shadows of the mind in French long ago (around 25 years ago) as I was not able to read a book in English around 13.  I think The Emperor's new mind was translated as "L'esprit, l'ordinateur et les lois de la physique" and referred to as EOLP.

Comment: @user36212 “What does it mean to say that a person can 'see a statement is true'? If it should mean anything, it means we have some way to demonstrate it is true.” Demonstrate from what?

Comment: @user76284 - well, that's rather the point. Generally when this argument is made, either what follows is some vague semi-philosophical statement, which I don't buy, or it means some mathematical proof starting from axioms. But either a computer can duplicate that proof (as I say, trivially) or you for some reason insist a human is allowed to work with more axioms than the computer. But why should we allow the latter? It's certainly not true (historically) that the human mind is somehow capable of recognising consistent axiom systems in general (this is a form of the vague semi-philosophy).

Comment: @user36212 Not saying computers *can’t* do it, but do you think we can recognize that, say, the successor axioms are consistent? I think I can, though I don’t know what it would mean to “prove it” from a simpler set of axioms.

Comment: @user76284 In fact, I think if you can recognize, for some simple consistent theory T to which the second incompleteness theorem applies, that it is consistent, then you can recognize that T+Con(T) is consistent, and that T+Con(T)+Con(T+Con(T)) is consistent, and so on, even though none of these can be proven from within T itself or T+Con(T).

Comment: @user76284 I don't think we can really claim to recognise any serious set of axioms as consistent. Peano, for example - I believe this is consistent, but I don't have any evidence. I don't see how this is stronger than a computer printing out 'I think PA is consistent'. Sure, you can point to physical reality which seems to obey PA (and be consistent), but this only tells you anything about small numbers. I think that all I'm doing when I say I believe PA is consistent is extrapolating hopefully from my experience; this is not a proof.

Comment: With more complicated schemes, say ZFC, I can still go through the same process, but now my experience is more limited and whatever this process is worth, it is certainly less. And ZFC is a rather well-chosen example; we think of it as somewhat natural today, but historically it's what came out of several attempts to provide foundations because the first few turned out not to be consistent. I don't see why I should trust my ability to recognise consistent systems above say Frege or Russell.

Comment: And in the end, I don't feel this process of extrapolating hopefully has any (mathematical) value. If you want to claim that this is the thing which a human can do and a computer cannot, then I will say that as far as mathematics is concerned, a computer can in principle do anything a human can.

Comment: @user36212 I don't necessarily disagree with your point about computers. What I'm more interested in is the rest. (1) Don't you think the successor axioms are consistent? I'm pretty sure I *know* they're consistent, at least if the word "know" ever applies to anything. (2) You say you don't have any evidence PA is consistent. Doesn't the lack of known contradictions constitute evidence for that? One could formalize this by saying one has evidence that a set of axioms is consistent if no proofs shorter than $n$ have yielded a contradiction. The larger $n$ is, the more evidence one has.

Comment: @user76284 How large do you think your n is? I would guess no one formally searched even up to 20, which is barely enough to prove even basic facts. Searching up to say 1000 length proofs is infeasible. But you’d surely be amazed if a major result had a less than 1000 character proof.

Comment: As to knowing something - I strongly believe consistency, strongly enough I’m not likely to do anything serious to mitigate the possibility of inconsistency in PA. That’s still not knowing for certain.

Comment: @user36212 My $n$ is not very large personally :-) Nevertheless, the fact that no contradiction has been found in over 130 years is *very* good evidence that PA is consistent. Now, surely you can think of *some* systems that you know are consistent. Otherwise it seems like the word "know" is being trivialized to nothingness (i.e. "you can't know anything").

Comment: @user76284 Well, Presburger arithmetic for example I know is consistent (I realise a philosopher might go into whether formal logic itself is consistent, I don't go that far).

Look at it this way: we use PA most of the time when we prove things; if we need more serious set theory, we might assume ZFC, sometimes we assume even more (usually with some kind of caveat that we are doing this only to make clean general statements not because we really need it, e.g. universes). For the last of these, I don't think we have any idea where to look for an inconsistency, nor do I think people tried.

Comment: So why should we assign a super-high level of confidence such as 'I know...' to such a system? And if we also cannot prove PA is consistent, where do we draw the line? For me, I'll say 'I know' to systems weak enough they can prove their own consistency. I believe PA strongly, but I think it's important to separate 'know' from 'strongly believe'. For ZFC, I am less certain, but I tend to believe that even if there is an inconsistency, it will be something we can clear up by weakening the axioms in some way that doesn't affect my proofs (I think this is a common belief, too).

Comment: Again, this is essentially the procedure used historically to get to ZFC. Sure, it was a big upheaval in the foundations of mathematics, but did it make any difference to any non-foundations theorem? Was there any result of Euler, Gauss... which was shown to be invalid because they were working with inconsistent foundations?

Comment: @user36212 I'd venture to say that I know that PA is consistent because I know [the finite rooted trees can be well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof), and this is basically as evident to me as the statement that the natural numbers can be well-ordered.

Comment: I think we're not really discussing mathematics any more... but anyway: If I'm discussing mathematics, I want to reserve 'know' for 'have a proof of', e.g. ZFC implies Fermat's Last Theorem, or 'Presburger arithmetic is consistent'. There are some systems I believe are consistent, but I don't know. There are some conjectures I believe are true, but I don't know. Otherwise, why would I bother trying to prove them if I already knew they were true? If you want to say this is just playing games with language: yes, I think it is. It's not really mathematics, for sure.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, computers can infer that the Gödel sentence is true. This is performed in a meta-theory which is stronger than the object theory, as it has to be.

For example, Russell O'Connor [formalized Gödel's incompleteness theorems in Coq](http://r6.ca/Goedel/goedel1.html). As he points out in Section 7.1, Coq can prove that the natural numbers form a model of Peano arithmetic $PA$. I cannot find in his formalization an explicit statement that Gödel's sentence is true (which is not to say it isn't there), but I am quite confident that it would take little effort to formalize such a statement.

*[This paragraphs has been made obsolete as the question was edited to address the issue.]* Also, let me point out that you might be confusing meta-theory with object-theory. Paulson uses the meta theory called "Nominal Isabelle" to prove Gödel's incompleteness theorem, but the way you phrased your question sounds as if you think Paulson's mechanised proof is carried out in $ZF$ without infinity.

Lastly, I would just like to say that I never understood how one could hold the position that ugly bags of mostly water are superior to machines in their ability to understand and create mathematics. A machine is not subject to uncontrollable chemical processes, fatigue, emotions, and temptations to sacrifice just a little bit of truth for a great deal of fame.

Comment: What if "uncontrollable chemical processes, fatigue, emotions" are necessary for the creation of mathematics?

Comment: "ugly bags of mostly water are superior to machines in their ability to understand and create mathematics" Well, aren't we machines too? As to uncontrollable chemical processes, take a glass of water and spill it first on yourself and then on your computer. Who will emerge in a better shape? Everything has its advantages and disadvantages compared to everything else. The question is not which technology is superior but how to combine the two in the most efficient way ;-)

Comment: Are we not machines programmed by billions of years of natural selection? Ah, fedja beat me to it -- I'd add that human-programmed machines are great at understanding whatever we tell them to think about, but telling them to think about "genuinely new and spontaneous mathematics" is tantamount to giving them uncontrollable chemical processes and emotions.

Comment: @AlecRhea Machines not designed to do mathematics.  That was a happy coincidence.  We are machines designed to breed and survive.  It's just luck that selected a high intelligence (and big tails on the distribution) as one of the methods of achieving that.

Comment: Did I say that machines were superior? I said I don't understood an ugly bag of mostly water when it says it is superior to machines.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Chemical processes and emotions are an obstruction to *verification* of correctness of mathematical arguments. To judge what piece of mathematics is worth doing, and which mathematicians are creative, for that one definitely needs a lot of chemicals and emotions. For creating mathematics that will be liked by humans one needs an equal part of understanding humans and of being good at mathematics. Machines are currently pretty bad at both.

Comment: I think ZF-I is equiconsistent to PA, in which case it can't prove G.  ZF of course can prove G, since it proves CON(PA).

Comment: I tried giving coffee to my computer. It fell asleep. Didn't give me any theorems. Terrible mathematician.

Comment: A machine may be very good at *creating* mathematics, but -- like a philosophical zombie or a Chinese room -- I don't see any reason to believe that it is capable of *understanding* it.

Comment: @AndrejBauer:  If you read both the papers I cited, you will see that the authors consider $ZF$ $-$ _Infinity_ (denoted $ZF^{*}$ in the Sieg-Field paper, and $HF$ in the Paulson paper) as the object-theories (as Sieg and Field write on pg. 320 of their paper, "The theory to be considered is $ZF^{*}$ ['*' should be an asterisk but the computer keyboard I am using has this instead], Zermelo and Fraenkel's theory of sets without the axiom of infinity", so that to me reads like $ZF^{*}$ is considered the object-theory--I edited my question in order to correct this misunderstanding).  It might

Comment: (cont.) interest you to know that in the Sieg-Field paper (see pp. 325-326) the machine proof divetails from the object-theory into the metatheory (TEM, i.e., Theory for Elementary Meta-Mathematics), then back into the object-theory again, for whatever that's worth....

Comment: @AndrejBauer:  The fact that Coq can prove that the natural numbers form a model  of $PA$ is, of course, important inasmuch as that shows that the computer which implements Coq has the rudiments of an 'intuition' that $ZF^{*}$ is consistent (by the Godel completeness theorem) so that the Lucas argument fails (seemingly) by its own criterion.  Any problems with this claim (and the inherent reasoning behind it)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin "Problems with this claim": (1) I'm not sure that being able to prove something shows that one has even the rudiments of an intuition about it. (Example: the "Homological Ring Theory" course that I got an A in as a grad student -- my proofs were fine, but my intuition was nonexistent.) (2) Although I have experienced intuitions, it's not very clear to me what rudiments of an intuition might be or what it might mean for a computer to have them.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: you're reading too much into a computer being able to check a proof formalized in Coq. It's not like the computer has any sort of motivation or intuition to do math. It's just a program, after all. You speak in terms of concepts that are outside of the realm of mathematics, you won't find many people willing to do so on this forum.

Comment: @AndreasBlass:  I find your  "Homological Ring Theory course" example very interesting.  How did you manage to produce such "fine proofs"  with "nonexistent intuition"?

Comment: @AndrejBauer:  According to O'Connor, "Coq is sufficiently powerful to prove the consistency of $PA$ by proving that the natural numbers model $PA$."  This sounds like it is much more than "a computer being able to check a proof formalized in Coq".  And as regards a computer not having any sort of motivation or intuition to do math, can't some very clever AI researcher figure out a way for a computer to at least mimic motivation and intuition to such a degree as to pass a Turing test?

Comment: When O'Connor says that he means that in the Calculus of Inductive Constructions (the theory which Coq implements and in which its proofs are written) the statement "the natural numbers model PA" can be derived. That is all. Coq simply verifies that the proof of this statement is correct (it also help the user construct such a proof). Whether this makes Coq "aware" of "what is going on" is a matter of a conversation that requires beer.

Comment: @AndrejBauer:  Regarding beer, how much?  As regards the rest of your comment:  Can Coq store the derived statement, "the natural numbers model $PA$" in its library of proved theorems and use that statement to prove more theorems (if so, then what more is needed except motivation)?  I am currently reading Martijn Vermaat's Master's  Thesis, "Infinitary Rewriting in Coq" (look under title on the Web) and am very impressed with Coq's power.  Are human mathematicians, when they prove theorems, "aware" of "what is going on" when they prove theorems?  And what are they aware of when they prove

Comment: (cont.) theorems?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: Have you used a proof assistant? If you're so interested in what they are, perhaps you should try using them. There are tutorials online that will help you get started.

Comment: @AndrejBauer:  I'll take a look. Thanks

Comment: @MikeShulman, if people are capable of understanding mathematics, then so too are machines. Indeed, there's lots of machines currently in existence that understand mathematics to a certain degree. Mike Shulman, goblin, etc.

Comment: @goblin You may be a machine (I have no way to tell for sure), but I am not.

Comment: I can testify to the fact that even though @MikeShulman churns out mathematics as if he were a steam engine, he is in fact not a machine.

Comment: @MikeShulman, what makes you say that a brain is not a machine?

Comment: @goblin What I said is that *I* am not a machine, because I am not a zombie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_zombie).  I'm willing to consider my brain (along with the rest of my body) to be a machine.

Comment: @MikeShulman, well, I don't believe in philosophical zombies. The way I see it, our brains determine the relationships between incoming sensory data and outgoing behavior. All actions you or I perform arise from the laws of physics. Ergo you don't need a theory of consciousness to predict what human beings are capable of. If "understanding" is physically-meaningful notion, then machines can understand things just the same as brains, since brains are machines. You seem to be invoking a non-physicalist theory

Comment: of consciousness. The problem with all such theories, in my opinion, is that they're inherently nonpredictive and untestable. And, in the context of the current discussion, that's especially problematic, since we're discussing what mathematics human beings are actually capable of. (My comments here are a bit disjointed because I'm posting from my phone and going back to edit things is too hard on this thing. Hopeful you get the gist of my point nonetheless.)

Comment: @MikeShulman, I think there's a universal property underlying all this. One can postulate all kinds of nonphysical notions and nonphysical distinctions ("we're all penetrated by a vast majestic non-physical field generated by all living things") but experience teaches us to be skeptical of such claims. To avoid wasting our time thinking about useless ideas and baseless claims, we instinctively focus in on the initial object in the category of ways of looking at the nature of things, because this is the smallest place containing all testable claims. My contention is that non-physical...

Comment: ...notions of consciousness do not exist in this initial object, and thus that such notions, by failing to comply with the usual accountability mechanisms that orient us in discussions of what's actually true and how we reached this conclusion, are rendered not particularly worthy of analysis or discussion.

Comment: @goblin I test my non-physical theory of consciousness by observing that I am in fact conscious.  I've never seen any purely physical theory even attempt to explain how consciousness could arise from physical objects.  I can imagine how physical processes in a computer or even a human body might produce *behavior* mimicking a conscious being, but all that is to say that they could produce a zombie.

Comment: When you say you don't believe in zombies, I assume you mean you believe that if physical processes in a computer or human body produced behavior mimicking a conscious being, then it would actually *be* conscious.  But if so, it is incumbent upon your theory to explain how exactly that consciousness would be produced.

Comment: Can an admin please kick off the bots, they're hogging this discussion thread with irrelevant stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @MikeShulman, there's increasingly a lot of discussion topics on the table. Is there somewhere more conducive to extended comments where we can have this discussion?

Comment: @goblin You can send me an email if you want.  Or we can just drop it; this is one of those conversations that seems unlikely to go anywhere useful.  I just didn't want the last paragraph of Andrej's post to go undisputed.

Comment: It got disputed plenty, precisely as I planned. There is a chat system on MO exactly for continuing discussions that arise in comments, but I don't see how to activate one for this discussion.

Answer (score 6):

One can try to rescue Lucas's reasoning by arguing that humans can see the consistency of ZF - Infinity (or any other formal system under consideration) by mathematical intuition, and then infer the Godel sentence by logic. The difference between the human mind and the computer is then taken to be this mathematical intuition, rather than the logic that follows it. I think Penrose has given this version.

This argument is problematic because humans clearly do not just look at a formal system and see whether it is consistent (except for very simple ones, perhaps). Instead we guess the consistency of sets of axioms by using various heuristics, mathematical experience, analogies to the physical world.... We could also equip the computer with a set of heuristics for guessing the consistency of formal systems. The only downside to this would be that the heuristics would likely get some things wrong and therefore output a false answer to some mathematical queries (thereby evading Godel/Turing problems).

But this is no big deal as humans also make mistakes. In particular, top mathematicians have made serious errors about the consistency of formal systems, most famously Frege writing an entire book in a formal system to Russell's paradox. Some mathematicians have even doubted the consistency of Peano arithmetic - either a few great mathematicians are wrong about this question, or almost all of them are.

So there does not seem to be any real difference between humans and machines on this point.

I believe this argument is essentially the same as one given by Turing in his paper *Computing Machinery and Intelligence* (where he also introduced the Turing test), 9 years before Lucas.

> The
>   result in question refers to a type of machine which is essentially a digital computer with
>   an infinite capacity. It states that there are certain things that such a machine cannot do. If
>   it is rigged up to give answers to questions as in the imitation game, there will be some
>   questions to which it will either give a wrong answer, or fail to give an answer at all
>   however much time is allowed for a reply. [ ..... ] This is
>   the mathematical result: it is argued that it proves a disability of machines to which the
>   human intellect is not subject.
>
> The short answer to this argument is that although it is established that there are
>   limitations to the powers of any particular machine, it has only been stated, without any
>   sort of proof, that no such limitations apply to the human intellect. But I do not think this
>   view can be dismissed quite so lightly. Whenever one of these machines is asked the
>   appropriate critical question, and gives a definite answer, we know that this answer must
>   be wrong, and this gives us a certain feeling of superiority. Is this feeling illusory? It is no
>   doubt quite genuine, but I do not think too much importance should be attached to it. We
>   too often give wrong answers to questions ourselves to be justified in being very pleased 
>   at such evidence of fallibility on the part of the machines. Further, our superiority can
>   only be felt on such an occasion in relation to the one machine over which we have
>   scored our petty triumph. There would be no question of triumphing simultaneously over
>   all machines. In short, then, there might be men cleverer than any given machine, but
>   then again there might be other machines cleverer again, and so on.

---

Lucas's article responds to Turing's:

> He argues that the limitation to
>   the powers of a machine do not amount to anything much. Although each individual machine
>   is incapable of getting the right answer to some questions, after all each individual human
>   being is fallible also: and in any case "our superiority can only be felt on such an occasion in
>   relation to the one machine over which we have scored our petty triumph. There would be no
>   question of triumphing simultaneously over all machines." But this is not the point. We are not
>   discussing whether machines or minds are superior, but whether they are the same. In some
>   respect machines are undoubtedly superior to human minds; and the question on which they
>   are stumped is admittedly, a rather niggling, even trivial, question. But it is enough,
>   enough to show that the machine is not the same as a mind. True, the machine can do many
>   things that a human mind cannot do: but if there is of necessity something that the machine
>   cannot do, though the mind can, then, however trivial the matter is, we cannot equate the two,
>   and cannot hope ever to have a mechanical model that will adequately represent the mind.

This argument seems to be "For each machine, there is some Godel sentence it cannot verify. There exists some mind that can verify all these Godel sentences. Therefore, (some) minds are not machines." The second premise is the problem - some Godel sentences take 150 years to state, say, and no human mind could understand them, let alone verify them.

He also responds to Turing again later, but it's a different argument of Turing's, so not relevant to my answer.

Comment: You might be interested in Kurt Ammon's arXiv preprint (arXiv:1302.1155v1 [cs.AI] 5 Feb 2013) preprint, "An Effective Procedure for Computing "Uncomputable" Functions (seeing that he wrote, "An automatic proof of Godel's incompleteness theorem," _Artificial Intelligence_, 61(2):  291-306, 1993).  It is somewhat like the Lucas argument, only using the notion of productive sets.

Comment: Also, Coq can prove that the natural numbers form a model of $PA$ (and therefore of $ZF^{*}$) and in this sense can have an 'intuition' of the consistency of arithmetic.  What say you?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin I don't see how your second comment contradicts or casts doubt on anything I said.

Comment: So you are saying then that one cannot rescue Lucas' reasoning  by arguing that humans can see the consistency of $ZF^{*}$ by mathematical intuition when Coq can show that the natural numbers form a model of  $ZF^{*}$?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin For any specific formal system, the fact that humans can see the consistency of that formal system by mathematical intuition doesn't rescue Lucas's reasoning, because one could construct a computer program that assumes the correctness of that formal system. (For instance, Coq in the case of $ZF^*$). To make Lucas's argument work you need to know that, for every formal system, humans can determine the consistency of that system, which is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with Lucas’ argument:

Any attempt to mechanize our mathematical intuitions is doomed to fail because the very fact of mechanization yields new intuitive knowledge, e.g. Goedel’s sentence, which is not captured by the machine.

The problem is that you have to know quite a lot about the machine to conclude that its corresponding Goedel’s sentence is true. For example, if you know that this machine produces only true sentences you may infer that its Goedel’s sentence is true (this is Tarski’s theorem) and if you know that this machine is consistent (i.e. does not produce contradictions) you may infer that its Goedel’s sentence is even provable (this is Goedel’s theorem).

But even the machine can prove that its Goedel’s sentence is provable if the machine is consistent, as commented by John Coleman before (this is Goedel’s theorem again).

On the other hand, it remains possible that there may exist (and even be empirically discoverable) a mathematical machine which in fact is equivalent to our mathematical intuitions. For example, I could be such a machine.

Lucas confused the incorrect proposition:

There is no machine which could capture all our mathematical intuitions.

With the correct proposition:

There is no machine which could capture all our mathematical intuitions and which we could understand well enough to see that its Goedel’s sentence is true.

Hence, as far as Goedel’s incompleteness theorem is concerned I could well be a machine. But if I am then I am definitely not capable of the complete knowledge of the machine, i.e. of the complete knowledge of myself.